# Webview hide CSS elements

Tags: android, android-webview, android-studio-3.0

I've been trying to alter my Webview app to not show the header of the source url that it loads. I've gone trough all the methods provided in Stack Overflow's history and havent't got any of them working - so i'm doing something right, or those aren't working anymore?

My goal is to find a way to affect the CSS of the page loaded to the webview app (hide the header and footer for example). Most of the methods provided here earlier based on Javascript, which is not familiar with me. I'm open for any help, since it is my first project that i'm building, and my knowledge at this point is not too good.

Here's my MainActivity.java at the moment:

package com.U247;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView WebView;
/* dawdaw */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.U247);

        WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            WebView.evaluateJavascript("var FunctionOne = function () {"
                    + "  try{document.getElementsByClassName('random-postaus')[0].style.display='none';}catch(e){}"
                    + "};", null);
        } else {
            WebView.loadUrl("javascript:"
                    + "var FunctionOne = function () {"
                    + "  try{document.getElementsByClassName('random-postaus')[0].style.display='none';}catch(e){}"
                    + "};");
        }
        WebView.loadUrl("https://thewebsite.com");
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (WebView.canGoBack()){
            WebView.goBack();

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay finally found a way to hide the CSS elements. Added the whole code below and the key was to use the onPageFinished method. While it is not perfect, and only activates after the whole page is loaded, it's still a valid method to hide elements in my case.

```
package com.U247;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView WebView;
/* dawdaw */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.U247);

        WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        /* HIDE UNWANTED CSS ELEMENTS */
        WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                // hide element by class name
                WebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('class-name-here')[0].style.display='none'; })()");
                // hide element by id
                WebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementById('header').style.display='none';})()");

            }
        });
        WebView.loadUrl("https://thewebsite.com");
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (WebView.canGoBack()){
            WebView.goBack();

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```